# PHP Rest request using Linnworks API and Inventory/CreateInventoryItemTitles

Tags: php, rest, api, post

I am trying to make a post request with the Linnworks API.

- http://apps.linnworks.net/Api/Method/Inventory-CreateInventoryItemTitles

More specifically push a new title, but I cannot get it to work.  I am querying their system just fine, so there is something clearly wrong with my formatting;

```
$CreateTitle = json_decode(Factory::GetResponse("Inventory/CreateInventoryItemTitles","inventoryItemTitles=[{StockItemId=00000000-4683-0000-88dc-00880000fc09&Source=Test&SubSource=Test&Title=Test}]",$authorization->Token, "https://api.linnworks.net/"));
```

The Linnworks support team have replied with;

For rowId generate random guid.  Here is my request body that went through fine:

```
inventoryItemTitles=[{"StockItemId":"797b268d-4fa5-4714-a96d-00d45608f2d6","Title":"New Title","Source":"EBAY","SubSource":"EBAY4","pkRowId":"ccbd77f6-f04a-404b-af36-f859747d5c20"}]
```

But this is not in php and they will not provide any assistance with php development.

So based on Brians advice, I have updated to this, however I am ;still experiencing a HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request.  So clearly still doing something wrong;

```
$object = [
 "StockItemId" => "00000000-4683-0000-88dc-00880000fc09",
 "Title" => "value2",
 "Source" => "value2",
 "SubSource" => "value2" 
 ];

$encoded = json_encode($object);
$CreateTitle = json_decode(Factory::GetResponse("Inventory/CreateInventoryItemTitles",$encoded,$authorization->Token, "https://api.linnworks.net/"));

// print_r($encoded);
```

Comment: You aren't sending php, you need to construct the JSON and send it serialised as a payload... to the API address... json_decode is for when you get the response back... You are needing json_encode on the correctly formed object.

Comment: I don't know what framework you are using in php but its not something I've encountered before... I suggest looking up how you send the payload... I'm unfamiliar with `Factory::GetResponse` I use cURL when doing these kinds of things... Also your link states the HTTP location is: `"https://eu1.linnworks.net//api/Inventory/CreateInventoryItemTitles"`. Why are you posting to `"https://api.linnworks.net/"` ?

Comment: php, not sure how to respond to everything else written.

Comment: If I try to run your code: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Factory' not found`. This is because its not native php. Need more info if you're going to get any help. And add your php framework into the tags. I've answered your initial question anyway, how to get the required formatting.

Comment: "I am querying their system just fine, so there is something clearly wrong with my formatting;"  I have updated the question with your suggestions.

Comment: So, it would seem my "data" is formatted correctly now as an encoded object (hope the terminology is correct), but the submission is incorrect.  Is that right?  I have the Linnworks SDK and have been using it to query data, this is my first Create/POST request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134589/discussion-between-stuart-and-brian-ramsey).

Answer (score 0):

you need to form your object like so:

```
<?php

 $object = [
    [
    "pkRowId" => "5c6dc399-f476-49a5-8c64-771310a25691",
    "Source" => "sample string 2",
    "SubSource" => "sample string 3",
    "Title" => "sample string 4",
    "StockItemId" => "5695ab85-829d-4f5c-bd88-f0b6943fd577"
  ],
  [
    "pkRowId" => "5c6dc399-f476-49a5-8c64-771310a25691",
    "Source" => "sample string 2",
    "SubSource" => "sample string 3",
    "Title" => "sample string 4",
    "StockItemId" => "5695ab85-829d-4f5c-bd88-f0b6943fd577"
  ]

];

 $encoded = json_encode($object);

 print_r($encoded);
```

Result:

```
[{"pkRowId":"5c6dc399-f476-49a5-8c64-771310a25691","Source":"sample string 2","SubSource":"sample string 3","Title":"sample string 4","StockItemId":"5695ab85-829d-4f5c-bd88-f0b6943fd577"},
{"pkRowId":"5c6dc399-f476-49a5-8c64-771310a25691","Source":"sample string 2","SubSource":"sample string 3","Title":"sample string 4","StockItemId":"5695ab85-829d-4f5c-bd88-f0b6943fd577"}]
```

This is what you send in the REST call as the payload `inventoryItemTitles=`, they want an array of objects..

Answer (score 0):

Turns out whilst in my my example lists the title as "sample string 4", the failing was caused by an ampersand! 'urlencode'